# Cannot read property '0' of undefined- Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have 2 nested NgFor loops, and I need to access value from them but when I try to do with ngModel and Index, it throws the error.

following is the html for it:

```
<tbody class="tb-space" *ngFor="let rate of
     rankingunitConfig.ratingLevels; let i=index;">
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center sticky-child">{{rate.levelNo}}</td>
        <td class="text-center sticky-child">{{rate.fromPoint}}</td>
        <td class="text-center sticky-child">{{rate.toPoint}}</td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let cal of populateScoreConfigTable; let j=index;">
            <td class="text-center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From score" [(ngModel)]="targetArray[i][j]">
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To score">
            </td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I resolve this ? I think my array is going empty in ngModel but when I try to populate it, it gives same error.

Comment: Please, add what's in the variable `rankingunitConfig`

Comment: it  is an array from 1 to 5 as values .

Comment: Can you please create a Stackblitz with the code in order to check it? It would be much easier :)

Comment: ngFor start from 0. Your array start at 1. That's why array[0] is undefined. You need to have array starting at zero, not at one. Fix this and you are good to go.

Comment: nope my array does not start at 1, it starts at 0 itself, 1,2,3,4,5 are values. But I got the solution and I posted it already, thank you for giving your time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the code and realized that my array is empty while I have been trying to access its [i][j] index.
So I populated the array first with dummy data and the problem was solved.
Thanks for all your help.